# Vim, how to scroll to bottom of a named buffer

Tags: vim, scripting

I have a vim-script which splits output to a new window, using the following command:

```
below split +view foo
```

I've been trying to find a way from an arbitrary buffer to scroll to the bottom of **foo**, or a setting to keep it defaulted to showing the bottom lines of the buffer.

I'm doing most of this inside of a python block of vim script.  So I have something like:

```
python << endpython
import vim
import time
import thread
import sys

def myfunction(string,sleeptime,*args):
    outpWindow = vim.current.window
    while 1:
        outpWindow.buffer.append("BAR")
        #vim.command("SCROLL TO BOTTOM OF foo")
        time.sleep(sleeptime) #sleep for a specified amount of time.

vim.command('below split +view foo')
thread.start_new_thread(myfunction,("Thread No:1",2))
endpython
```

And need to find something to put in for **vim.command("SCROLL TO BOTTOM of foo")** line

Comment: Is it the *scrolling* that is important or do you simply want to be delivered to the bottom of the buffer?

Comment: I want it to stay at the bottom of the buffer as the things being appended exceed the viewable space.  More or less like a normal console window.

Answer (score 4):

I usually record the new buffer number (`let b_tgt = bufnr('%')`), and more precisely its windows number. Then, in a `try-finally` block I record the current window number (`let w_orig = bufwinnr('%')`), jump to the window where I need to do something (`:exe w_tgt.' wincmd w'`), do the thing (`:normal! G` in your case), and jump back (in the `:finally` clause) to the current window (at the beginning of the action -> `:exe w_orig.' wincmd w'`).

Now if other buffers may have been opened, or closed, we need to look for the target window each time as its number may have changed. This is done with `bufwinnr(b_tgt)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I wanted to set the cursor of a different window without switching to it. Lucily in Neovim there is quite a comprehensive API, the functions are starting with `nvim_...`. I solved it more or less in this way in vimscript:

```
let l:bufname = "foo"
let l:lnum = getbufinfo(l:bufname)[0]['linecount']
let l:win_id = bufwinid(l:bufname)
call nvim_win_set_cursor(l:win_id, [l:lnum, 0])
```

of course if you want to act on the current window, you can just use the `setpos()` function available in all vim versions.